# iMessage to Mac when logged off

Tags: macos, ios, messages

Quick easy question - if iPhone iMessages are synced to Mac, then somehow you get logged out of messages on the Mac, would any iMessages sent by your phone while you were logged out on your Mac show up on your Mac when you log back into messages on your Mac? Or are those messages sent while you weren't logged in just on iPhone and there will be a gap in your Mac messages for the period you were logged out?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, iMessage syncing is not reliable but it does work most of the time. As a result, it's difficult to ascertain a definitive answer. The intended behavior is as you described it and there should be no gap in Mac message history.

However, for me, it doesn't sync 100% of messages all of the time. It does sync most of the time. The other thing that can happen is a time delay. For example, I booted up my Mac after an extended period of having it off and no messages came in. The next day when I booted it up, everything came in.

If most of your messages are not syncing, I suggest disabling iMessage on your iMac and iPhone and then re-enabling it both places.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Very helpful, I'll try the disabling method. One additional question related to the same issue - what happens to any deleted messages that were deleted from phone while logged out of computer? So, for instance, I keep running against my storage limit. So I go and delete big long text strands to free up space. However, what happens to those texts I deleted that were sent while Mac wasn't logged in messages? Not a big problem, but might lose a couple contacts/phone numbers. Just wonder if you think they would sync along with everything else when I disable and sync back up, or the

Comment: Deleted messages do not affect other devices, as of iOS 9 and OS X 10.11.  The key is that iMessages don't really "sync". They queue up, similar to the days of POP email, and are received in multiple locations. If you delete a thread off of your iPhone, they will remain on your Mac, and visa versa. You could also confirm on your devices by deleting a non-important thread or message.